# Get GridView DataKeyName and use it in external button

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, webforms

I'm using ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework).

I have a GridView with auto-generated "Select" button, and an "Approve" button which is outside of the GridView. I want to click on the "Select" link to get the DataKeyName (ViewingRequestID) and use it in the "Approve" button's onClick method.

When I run my code, I click on "Select", it gives the correct ViewingRequestID. But when I click on "Approve" after that, the ViewingRequestID becomes 0.

How do I get the value to remain the same?

HTML

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvViewingRequests" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Horizontal" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ViewingRequestID" PageSize="5" OnRowCommand="gvViewingRequests_RowCommand" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ViewingRequestID" HeaderText="Viewing Request ID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ParentID" HeaderText="Parent ID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentName" HeaderText="Student Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentID" HeaderText="Student ID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateCreated" HeaderText="Date Created" />
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F4F4FD" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#5A4C9D" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D8D8F0" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#3E3277" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind

```
ViewingRequest viewingRequest = new ViewingRequest();

    protected void gvViewingRequests_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        viewingRequest.viewingRequestID = Convert.ToInt32(gvViewingRequests.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text);  
    }

    protected void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        int errorCode = viewingRequest.changeStatus(viewingRequest.viewingRequestID, "A");

        if (errorCode == 0)
        {
            displayViewingRequests();
            lblMsg.Text = $"Viewing Request {viewingRequest.viewingRequestID} approved.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: HTTP is stateless so what you set in RowCommand is lost by the time you click Approve. You could just [use the SelectedItem property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) in the Approve click event.

Comment: You could put the Id in the viewstate